# Angular 2 ngClass is not rendering "icon" word,

Tags: angular

Angular2 ngClass is not rendering `icon` word, we tried that all combinations are working well but `icon` is not working

For Example

```
<i [ngClass]="{'facebook icon': comment.site == 'Facebook', 'instagram icon': comment.site=='Instagram', 'youtube icon': comment.site == 'youtube'}"></i>
```

After render this code will be

```
<i class="facebook"></i>
```

But

```
<i [ngClass]="{'facebook test': comment.site == 'Facebook', 'instagram icon': comment.site=='Instagram', 'youtube icon': comment.site == 'youtube'}"></i>
```

After render this code will be

```
<i class="facebook test"></i>
```

I want to render it like this

```
<i class="facebook icon"></i>
```

But it seems impossible, maybe it is a bug.

Comment: If `<i>` element need `icon` class, you should use in `class="icon"`. Then use `ngClass` for other needed.